# Whereis file command issueing newline with file:

Tags: linux

What does this behavior mean. I type:

```
whereis Dotfiles
```

It returns on newline

```
Dotfiles:
```

I ran this word for word in this order (No such directory "Dotfiles" existed prior:

```bash
$git clone git://github.com/haridas/Dotfiles.git

$cd Dotfiles

$pwd
<path to gitproject>/Dotfiles

$git submodule init
$git submodule update
```

-- Note, yes, I did run at as /Dotfiles because I did not notice it when I copy/ pasted. I am a noob.

Comment: At a guess it couldn't find Dotfiles?

Comment: What is Dotfiles? Is it directory, file or something else?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know. New to Linux and I was just following this guide to get my IDE working: http://haridas.in/vim-as-your-ide.html

Comment: Got it. Dotfiles is the directory that is being cloned. If you want to find/search the Dotfiles Directory, run "find . -iname Dotfiles -type d"

Comment: That just returns a newline for me, no output (Ubuntu).

Comment: Looks like your clone failed . What was the output of git clone ?

Answer (score 0):

It simply states that it couldn't find Dotfiles. whereis command is used to find the source, binary, and manuals sections for specified commands or files. What is Dotfiles ? A directory, symlink, file ?

Answer (score 0):

In bash, the `whereis` command is used to "locate the binary, source, and manual page files for a command"(straight from the man page for `whereis`). From the tutorial you posted in the comments it appears that `Dotfiles` is a directory.

You could use the `locate` command in conjunction with `grep` to find the `Dotfiles` directory:

```
locate Dotfiles | grep "/Dotfiles\$"
```

Or assuming the `Dotfiles` directory is somewhere in your home directory you could use the following `find` commmand:

`find ~ -iname Dotfiles -type d`

Comment: hmmm locate must not be installed by default. If you would like this command, you can type `sudo apt-get install locate` in the terminal to install it. It comes in pretty handy for me. What version of ubuntu are you running?

Comment: The command just returns a new prompt. No output at all and 12.04.

Comment: I just replied up. Can you reply to that ?

Comment: which command did you run and where did you clone `git://github.com/haridas/Dotfiles.git` to?

Comment: If you look at the article under the title "Setup Vim from Scratch". All I did was run each command line by line. I have no idea how things work yet.

Comment: hmmm okay this would be my last guess `sudo find / -type d -name Dotfiles`. if it doesn't show up in that I don't think you actually cloned `Dotfiles` from github.

Comment: I know where I messed up i think... When he wrote this: $pwd
<path to gitproject>/Dotfiles

$git submodule init
$git submodule update ---- What was I suppose to put for path to gitproject..?